# Javascript files get damaged with cpprest SDK backend (C++ / Angular2)

Tags: javascript, c++, angular, rest

I have a backend service which is supposed to be used on multiple computers/platforms. This backend is written using CppRest SDK. 
To control the service I have written a frontend using Typescript/Angular2. The generated .js files are returned by the backend -i.e. they are saved on the drive of the computer running the backend service.

When running the server app on Windows computers, there seems to be no problem. However when I made an OSX build, the main .js file is bringing on syntax errors in the client's browser. It seems to be damaged somehow (almost like chunk of text was missing in the middle of the script).

I thought this could be an encoding issue, but the problem remains the same after resaving the scripts with utf8 encoding, adding utf8 charset to the Content-Type header of the response on the backend side and defining script's charset in the Index.html.

The weird thing is that when I try to use the service from the browser of the computer actually running the backend app, everything is allright.

I can't wrap my head around this. Any thoughts? 
Thanks.